# Data Scraping with php

Tags: php, screen-scraping, mining

I want to scrape data using php. But I don't understand where im wrong. 
I want to receive "15,50 TL" text. Thank you

```
<?php

function find($start, $close, $where)
{
    @preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') .
    '(.*?)'. preg_quote($close, '/').'/i', $where, $m);
    return @$m[1];
}

$url = "https://www.bynogame.com/Knight-Online/Gold-Bar";

$fulldata = file_get_contents($url);

$akara = find('<td align="center" nowrap="nowrap">','<form name="urunayrinti38154"></form></td>',$fulldata);

print_r($akara);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `$start` and `$close` strings are nowhere to be found in the page.

There is a `<td  align="center" nowrap="nowrap">`, with *2 spaces* between the `td` tag name and the `align` attribute, and there's a `<form name="urunayrinti38154">` string without the rest.

IMHO, a better approach is to use either a DOM parsing library, such as Symfony's [DomCrawler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html), or PHP's own  [XML Manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) functions, such as [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).